# Check node exists in XML using a Choice in Mule

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using a choice component in Mule 3.7.3 which will follow one flow if the XML contains an node called user.

I continue to get errors using different variations of syntax.  Does anyone know how I can test that the XML contains the user node?

Choice code:

```xml
<choice doc:name="Check to send confirmation">
    <when expression="#[xpath:boolean(/user/text()[1])==&quot;true&quot;]">
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <logger message="#['Error creating user - Confirmation not sent']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression `#[xpath3('//*:user',payload,"NODE") != null]` this will return `true` if node exists irrespective of empty node and `false` if node doesn't exists. If you want to put check on node value use `#[xpath3('//*:user',payload,"STIRNG")]`

Refer this for more details

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath#return-type-string-optional

Hope this helps.